# Javascript precision solution?

Tags: javascript, precision

My program generates numerical inputs for a quiz. Due to floating point issues (presumably), for example, y=1.5575 is represented y=1.557499999999999. No real surprise here. But when I want to display this number to 4 significant digits, y.toPrecision(4) returns '1.557' when the 'correct' value should be 1.558. I can get around this issue by calling .toPrecision() twice, first with a higher precision:

```
console.log(y1);  // 1.557499999999999
console.log(y1.toPrecision(4)); // 1.557 'wrong'
console.log((Number(y1.toPrecision(8))).toPrecision(4)); // 1.558 'correct'
```

Does anyone know of a cleaner solution to this issue?

Comment: What's the desired algorithm? Banker's rounding? (why 1.558 and not 1.557?)

Comment: No, it's not about currency (if that is what Banker's rounding refers to). I'm building quizzes for engineering students and generate individual inputs to questions based on student ID. Inputs randomly generated, then displayed to 3 or to 4 significant digits.

Comment: Banker's rounding means "round to an even digit when at exactly 0.5 between them". Why 1.558 and not 1.557? It's not clear what the logic you're looking for is

Comment: Thanks for that info about Banker's rounding; I knew 'rounding to even' but not as Banker's rounding.

The input is supposed to be 1.5575 which is 1.558 to 4 sig digs. But 1.557499999 is 1.557 to 4 sig digs.

Comment: Ok, so what sort of algorithm are you trying to implement here? It's still not at all clear what the logic you want is

Comment: Pick a [library](https://dev.to/fvictorio/a-comparison-of-bignumber-libraries-in-javascript-2gc5), implement. Given your requirements, `bignumber.js` is the one you want.

Comment: Because the desired value of 1.5575 is displayed/stored as 1.55749999..., the result to 4 sig digs is not what it 'should' be. I know why this is happening but am looking for a cleaner solution to getting the 'correct' result based on the value 1.5575.

Comment: Why do you want rounding to 1.558 and not 1.557? 1.5575 is halfway between those - for the general case, how do you decide between them? You have to pick a rounding algorithm to use, can't really answer without knowing what sort of logic you're looking for. Always round up? Round up when exactly halfway between, otherwise round normally? Banker's rounding?

Comment: @CertainPerformance maybe because `(1.5575).toPrecision(4)`-> `1.558`. Btw for OP, the usual multiply until its an integer and then divide back will do. But this would need to be done before you ever get that 1.557499999999999 because there is then no way to know if it was a legit floating number or an imprecision (that is depending on where you get your data from).

Comment: @CertainPerformance For truncating the digit 5, I want to round up as is performed by the javascript Number.toPrecision() method. The issue is to recognise that 1.55749999.... should really be 1.5575 in my case. Applying toPrecision() twice does solve the issue, rounding first to 1.5575000 and then to 1.558.

Comment: @CertainPerformance I do have a utils.toSigDigs(number, sigDigs) method that wraps the toPrecision() method because question inputs are often to 3 sig digs unless the first non-zero digit is a 1 when 4 sig digs are required. (engineering weirdness). I can put the extra call to toPrecision() in that method but was wondering if there was a more readable way of coding it.

Comment: @marblewraith I don't want to include a library for a relatively simple problem for which I have a (somewhat inelegant) solution. And, from reading the documentation in the library README, it's not clear that this library would solve this particular issue.

Comment: There are other methods, but your current method calling `toPrecision` twice (or `toFixed` followed by `toPrecision`) looks like the best / shortest solution IMO

Comment: @Kaiido Would you recommend multiplying to an int and then dividing back over two calls to `toPrecision()`?

Comment: Yes definitely. Fix whatever produced the imprecision, the moment you are presenting us is already too late.

Comment: The 2x`toPrecision` is a hack to get around floating point arithmetic.  I am not confident that will yield consistent reliable results; because it will always depend on what your toPrecision(5) yields before you call toPrecision(4); and there's no way to determine if it's due to floating point arithmetic, or if the value was accurate.  If it's not floating point error and the number is what it should be, your toPrecision(5) converts .000445 to .00045 and your toPrecision(4) would convert that to .0005, when it should have been .0004 all along. Best bet is to use bignumber.js

Comment: @Mike Good point. I'll investigate further.